# Preciso de um select que se o resultado for 0 ou null ele nao exibir o botao

Tags: php, mysql

Olá preciso que se não tiver link na coluna link1 da tabela o botao não exibe, o codigo no xampp funciona porem na hospedagem não está indo nao sei porque motivo, o botão exibe e não tem link ou seja é para não exibir o botao. segue o php

```
<?php
$dados1 = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT p.produto, p.link1 from clientes c
JOIN infos i
ON c.id = i.idcliente
JOIN produtos p
ON i.idproduto = p.id WHERE p.id='$id'");

$num1 = mysqli_fetch_object($dados1);

if ($num1 == 0):

else :
    echo "<div class='pro-button2'>
                    <a href='$link1'>MediaFire</a>
                    </div><div style='float:left;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
endif;
?>
```

se tiver link = mostra o botao
Se nao tiver link = não mostra o botao

Comment: Você deve quebrar a string `<a href='+"$link1+"'>MediaFire</a>`

Comment: Então  mas oque nao estou entendendo porque ele está dando echo no botao sendo que na coluna o valor é NULL pois não tem link no tal id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Com esta consulta será retornado o número de registros que contiverem um link e produto com o mesmo ID que lhe for informado.

```
SELECT count(*) 'linhas' FROM  clientes c
JOIN infos i ON c.id = i.idcliente
JOIN produtos p ON i.idproduto = p.id 
WHERE p.id='$id' AND p.link1 IS NOT NULL
```

A partir deste código você poderá adaptar conforme o tipo de dado armazenado no campo `p.link1`.

Comment: Então, eu preciso que se não tiver link na coluna ele não me da nenhuma informação, agora se tiver link ele me retorna um botão, ja tentei de diversas maneiras e não esta indo

Comment: De certa forma, é exatamente isso que este código faz, se o resultado dele for 0 (zero), quer dizer que não existe nenhum registro no banco que satisfaça seus critérios, se retornar algo diferente de zero, é porque existe um registro.

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo porque na hospedagem mesmo assim continua dando echo no botao e no servidor local xampp da tudo certo

Comment: Toda consulta vai lhe retornar um conjunto de dados, então você tem que especificar o dado que quer comparar, creio que no seu caso, dentro do `if` deva ficar `$num1->linhas = 0`. Veja se isso irá funcionar para você. Obs: editei o código para renomear o `count()`

Comment: No xampp deu certo, porem na hospedagem ainda continua exibindo o botão, no id aonde nao existe link ele entende que tem link por exemplo
| 1 |   NULL  | link2 |
a hospedagem parece que não está entendendo esse null

Comment: Consegui, baseado no seu código usei apenas o `AND p.link1 IS NOT NULL` e resolveu